# Js: What happens when curly brackets enclose the variable declaration?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the following expression.

`const {
  TARGET = 'http://localhost:8080',
  PORT = 80
} = process.env;`

How does variable declaration enclosed by curly brackets work?
And how does the value assignment for `process.env` works?
Does this type of expression have a name?

Comment: This is known as [`Object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: in simple terms it is like Unpacking fields/properties from objects

Comment: The assignment within the curly brackets is setting default values which apply if `process.env` does not have the respective property name.

Comment: Thank you @palaѕн that's really helpful

Comment: Thank you @TapanDave for the explanation.

Comment: Thank you @connexo for the explanation that resolves my problem.